# Creating Image Button in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, image, api, button, maps

I want to insert a logo into my Google Maps that hovers over the map and links to a website, using Google Maps JavaScript API. I already know how to create buttons, but not how to insert images into those buttons. How would I do this?

Comment: Can I see your code first?

Comment: Please post [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can push elements by id into the map by specifying a position; see my example code below (it'll take you in the right direction).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Ilan's Test</title>
    <style>
        .pac-container {
            z-index: 9999;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>



    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch Map
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ilan's Map</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <div id="mlogo" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                            <center><a href="http://www.reviewsmaker.com" target="_new"><img src="https://dcnetworks.ie/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/placeholder-logo-2.png" style="z-index:9999;"></a></center>
                        </div>
                        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" style="z-index:9999;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container" id="map-canvas" style="height:300px;z-index:9995;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyAxBhvzi2eGU7HbBb5cNw5lAkb1eODMG3s"></script>
<script>
    function init() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: {
                lat: 12.9715987,
                lng: 77.59456269999998
            },
            zoom: 12
        });


        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('mlogo'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
            searchBox.set('map', null);


            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var i, place;
            for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
                (function(place) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                        position: place.geometry.location
                    });
                    marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
                        if (!this.getMap()) {
                            this.unbindAll();
                        }
                    });
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


                }(place));

            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            searchBox.set('map', map);
            map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(), 12));

        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>

</html>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Ilan's Test</title>
    <style>
        .pac-container {
            z-index: 9999;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>



    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch Map
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ilan's Map</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <div id="mlogo" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                            <center><a href="http://www.reviewsmaker.com" target="_new"><img src="https://dcnetworks.ie/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/placeholder-logo-2.png" style="z-index:9999;"></a></center>
                        </div>
                        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" style="z-index:9999;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container" id="map-canvas" style="height:300px;z-index:9995;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyAxBhvzi2eGU7HbBb5cNw5lAkb1eODMG3s"></script>
<script>
    function init() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: {
                lat: 12.9715987,
                lng: 77.59456269999998
            },
            zoom: 12
        });


        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('mlogo'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
            searchBox.set('map', null);


            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var i, place;
            for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
                (function(place) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                        position: place.geometry.location
                    });
                    marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
                        if (!this.getMap()) {
                            this.unbindAll();
                        }
                    });
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


                }(place));

            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            searchBox.set('map', map);
            map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(), 12));

        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make element appear over a map with the position absolute property in combination with the z-index property. See the linked jsFiddle

```
 #map_div{
  z-index : 0;
 }
img{
  position : absolute;
  display : inline;
  top : 100px;
  left : 100px;
  z-index : 1;
}
```

See jsFiddle 
     http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/8774/